# How to import/ include string in cpp

Tags: c++, namespaces, include

I would like to use the string class.
Should I also involve `using namespace std;`?

I thought `#include <string>` would be enough but in CLion when only one of these two (namespace or include) is absent, there are some errors.

What makes things more complicated, is that there is `<string>` or `<strings.h>`. What's the difference?

Comment: `#include <string>`, then use `std::string`. Standard headers have no extension.

Comment: "when only one of these two are absent". 

Two what?

Comment: The only thing `using namespace std;` does is it allows you to not write `std::` before names from the standard library. You still need `#include`s.

Comment: About [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Comment: @Quentin you meant <string.h> by "Standard headers"?

Comment: I think @Quentin means "standard library headers", but see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ the `using` statement is not related to including the functionality of that namespace (or type).  Instead, it allows you to use the namespace in the statement without a namespace prefix in the rest of the current scope (or compilation unit if you have the statement in global scope) after the `using` statement.

So you could either write

```
#include <string>

std::string my_string;
```

or

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string my_string;
```

As others have mentioned - the first version is more recommended than the second, because there's usually a reason that things are in their own namespace (such as the `std` namespace here).  If you have a blanket `using` statement you may get unexpected name clashes or other issues.  This is especially true if you do it in a header file, which you should never do unless you know exactly what the results will be and where.

Comment: Nothing wrong with being pedantic when it comes to programming!

Answer (score 6):

`<string>` is C++ and provides the `std::string` class.

`<string.h>` is C (the C++ equivalent is `<cstring>`) and only provides functions to work on `char*`.

Don't use `using namespace std;` (see the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines)).

Comment: Functions from `cstring`/`string.h` comprise e. g. memset, strchr, strlen, ... (printf family, incontrast, comes from `cstdio`/`stdio.h`).

Comment: I don't understand what "<string> is C++ and provides the std::string class." means. Is it that something like interface of string exists in std , but not implemented yet? And if I include <string> then, I kinda imported the implemented-real string>?

Comment: Not sure if the guidelines reference is good – there are good points in, but referencing another non-standard library excessively (GSL) is at least questionable in my eyes...

Comment: @Rhee `#include <string>` is what you need; `<string>` was short for the header named 'string' which defines an equally named class in namespace `std`.

Comment: @Aconcagua The GSL is an implementation of Core Guidelines verification. The link itself is the official one, supported by members of the C++ committee.

Comment: Then question arises: Why doesn't it enter the standard directly (in namespace `std`)???

Comment: This is a quite recent effort of adding guidelines, so it takes time. You can actually see some of the content of the GSL that have made their way in the standard.